# What is the parameter 'fragment' on win_xml module?

Tags: ansible, ansible-module

I have very limited knowledge on XML and not sure what does `fragment` parameter is used for.

```
- name: Apply sslEnabledProtocols to Tomcat's server.xml
  community.windows.win_xml:
    path: C:\Tomcat\conf\server.xml
    xpath: '//Server/Service[@name="Catalina"]/Connector[@port="9443"]'
    attribute: 'sslEnabledProtocols'
    fragment: 'TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2'
    type: attribute
```

Comment: did reading [the fine manual](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/community/windows/win_xml_module.html#parameter-fragment) not help you?

Comment: No. It doesn't really tell much.

Comment: Then edit your question to explain what you do know, what parts of the documentation confuse you, because as written your question is too vague for anyone to give you a specific answer